# How can I add an object to core data at specific index

Tags: core-data, indexing

What I really want is an persistent ordered list.  And after a years learning on xcode had the hubris to tackle Core Data for it.

So I added core data, copied the boiler-plate code and got it working with a single entity and a single attribute... to an extent.

What I would like to do is, at a specific index, insert a new object lower in the pecking order with all the ones above it shifting up a position.  Googling seems to point to it being possible since ios5; but there is little code to get my paws on.

Have I missed out something glaringly obvious in setting up my core-data to make it indexable?  Adding a NSOrderedSet as a parallel attribute?  Or does something like Magic Records do it well with a simple line of code?

Or am I on a hiding to nothing?

Many thanks.
Bee

Answer (score 0):

what you probably want to do is use an existing field to sort your query, or add a field specifically for sorting.

once you have a field to sort on its pretty easy to add a NSSortDescriptor to your fetch request.

something like this should work.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"fieldToSortOn" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

Comment: A very sound answer, my thanks.
Have you any idea about the ios5 self-indexing thing?  It seems to be woefully under documented.